# Can't center my social media icon

Tags: css, icons, center

I'm trying to display my social media icons like this:

```
<div class ="social">
    <div class="bordered"><a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"><i><img src="images/about/facebook.png" width="25" height="25" alt="" border="0" align=""></i></a></div>
</div>
```

but my website displays these icons from left to right [like this](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8216c33). When I delete/remove the whole "bordered" div and replace it with an image, with a word or with any element, I see it in the middle. The problem is I can't have the div called "bordered" on middle/center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using center tags which are obsolete. Use margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;

Comment: Aw...! It's centered now. I don't know how to thank you.